# What's the simplest way to check if database exists in MSSQL using VB.NET?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I'm trying to check if a database exists in the Microsoft SQL Server, what's the simplest way to do that? I just want it to return a true or false value then I would create a database if it doesn't exist. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just try to open a connection to that database? If an exception occurs you know the database either doesn't exist or isn't accessible.

Comment: Have a look on this :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/5d7b188e-17ba-41ff-98cb-eb783a587c41/check-if-database-exists

Comment: @User999999: This CAN indicate that the db is not existing, but maybe the db is existing and you don't have permissions? Not a clean solution imho

Comment: @CeOnSql true...... but assuming the user has the rights to create a database, then he certainly has the rights to access databases on that paticular instance. Your solution isn't waterproof aswell. What if the user doesn't have rights to access sys.databases....?

Comment: @User999999 If you just create a login on sql server (only a login, without any permissions on any database), this login will be able to do the query on sys.databases.

Comment: @CeOnSql: you start already with the assumption that such login (or the user knows the details of that loging) does exist, what if it doesn't? your query won't get executed (although) the database may exist, and the user will continue in the assumption that the database does not exist.

Comment: haha is see we are now at "but what if", "but what if"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect to a system-db (master, msdb, tempdb or model) - because you can be sure that they exist! Then you can select the list of database like this:

```
select * from sys.databases
```

or if you want to know if a specific db exists:

```
select * from sys.databases where name = 'NameOfYourDb'
```

If you connect without a database name in your connection string (belongs to which provider you are using) you should automatically be connect to your default database (which is "master" by default)

Answer (score 4):

Try below one

```
Declare @Dbname varchar(100)

SET @Dbname = 'MASTER'

if exists(select * from sys.databases where name = @Dbname)
select 'true'
else 
select 'false'
```

this is specially for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query :

```
select * from sys.databases where [name] = <name of database>
```